# Is it a bad idea to make different-sized dogs sleep in different rooms?

Tags: dogs, psychology, sleep

As we are getting further into winter, the temperature gradient in my house (at night) has increased: the conservatory is cold, the kitchen is room-temperature, and the living room is warm (there are lots of radiators in there).

Now, I have three dogs: a small Cavachon with thin fur, a medium-sized Labernese with quite thick fur, and a huge Bernese mountain dog with very thick fur.

Is it a good idea to make these dogs sleep in different rooms (the Cavachon in the living room, the Labernese in the kitchen, and the Bernese in the conservatory), so that they are at their most comfortable temperature, or is it better to make them all sleep in the same room (making at least two of them uncomfortable)? Will making them sleep in different rooms "separate the pack" and create tension between them, or will they understand that they are being separated because they have different physical needs?

Comment: Why can't they all just have access to the whole house and sleep wherever they want?

Comment: @JamesJenkins They end up coming upstairs and walking along the landing (it's got a squeaky floor, so it keeps us up).

Comment: Also, then the whole house gets cold, and nobody wins.

Comment: Would a baby gate (for example, something like [Safety 1st Nature Next Bamboo Gate](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001PYQWXY)) work at the bottom of the stairs? Effectively keeping them downstairs to let them choose their preferable place, as James Jenkins mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what your "cold" temperature would be, but keep in mind dogs do have a higher body temperature than humans. I don't think keeping them in separate rooms is 'bad' for the pack, but you may end up with unwanted behavior like barking, whining, destruction of furniture or doors depending on how comfortable they are being alone/separated from you or the other dogs.

If your dogs have been crate trained, I would suggest putting them in cates at night if you wanted to keep them in the separate rooms.

Why not keep them in your bedroom at night?